# Tag Synonym: feats-of-strength > achievements

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have suggested a tag synonym for [feats-of-strength](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feats-of-strength) to [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements) as part of the clean up, can I get some votes on this?

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/achievements/synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just cast the fourth upvote for the synonym, so this is now complete.